# RestKit 0.2 — RKManagedObjectRequestOperation targetObject == null

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I can't figure out how to set the targetObject on postOperation. Right now all my postObject methods are working fine, and mapping response data from the server to my objects. However managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest does not do that, and the log I have for targetObject returns null.

I tried setting it manually (see my code comment below) — but then I get back an error saying the managed object context do not match (one is null). Is this because of the threading? Anyway around this?

```
// post image

// create request
postRequest = [RKObjectManager.sharedManager multipartFormRequestWithObject:media method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:path parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:media.imageData name:@"userfile[]" fileName:filename mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

// create operation
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *postOperation = [RKObjectManager.sharedManager managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:postRequest managedObjectContext:viewController.managedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {

    NSLog(@"operation.targetObject: %@", operation.targetObject);

} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"post image error: %@", error);

}];
// postOperation.targetObject = media;

// enqueue operation
[RKObjectManager.sharedManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:postOperation];

// monitor upload progress
[postOperation.HTTPRequestOperation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"bytesWritten: %d, totalBytesWritten: %lld, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: %lld", bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
```

This is the error I'm receiving when I comment out postOperation.targetObject = media;

```
2012-12-14 20:04:36.256 Keepsayk Alpha[1966:1503] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Serious Core Data error: requested existing object with ID 0x1f805a30 <x-coredata:///Media/t0FEC53CF-F383-4E7E-8568-38F42EA839453> in context <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x1fa9a790>, instead got an object reference in context (null). This may indicate that the objectID for your target managed object was obtained using `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:error:` in the wrong context.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is probably happening because the `NSManagedObject` had a temporary managed object ID when it went into the request operation. You may be able to get back to the first implementation just by obtaining that permanent ID, if that's desirable. It may make sense to update `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` to just obtain the ID in all cases if necessary rather than throwing the warning.

Otherwise your subclass implementation looks like a fine solution.

Comment: I get the permanent ID by saving it to my MOC? So I would save locally before sending it off to be uploaded?

Comment: Saving the MOC will obtain a permanent managed object ID, but it will also push the change up the MOC hierarchy and possibly commit the object to the persistent store. You can also obtain them for unsaved objects by calling `obtainPermanentIDsForObjects` (which you do in the subclassed method). When you obtain one for a temporary object, it enables you to fetch that object from any child context of the context it currently resides in. `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` creates a new child context, so this will make the object visible in the object request operation's mapping context.

Comment: I see. Is there any reason you're not doing this in  managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest I see if I call postObject it's being done automatically by appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject. I'm assuming it's because the no object is being passed in, so it needs to be done manually?

Comment: Also, if I moved this the permaniate ID assignment to my code where I'm preparing the image for uploading, where would I assign my operation.targetObject? Is the success block too late?

Comment: Well you can't do it in `managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:` because you don't have an object to work with. It could be done in `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`, but I've tried to make the API's predictable so that it does what you tell it there and keep all of the opinionated configuration in the object manager.

Comment: You'll need to set the `targetObject` property before you either `start` the operation or enqueue it to an `NSOperationQueue` (i.e. calling `enqueueObjectRequestOperation:`). Otherwise it will be executing.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by creating my own method in RKObjectManager:

```
- (RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *)managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
                                                                       object:(id)object
                                                         managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
                                                                      success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success
                                                                      failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithHTTPRequestOperation:[self HTTPOperationWithRequest:request] responseDescriptors:self.responseDescriptors];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];
    operation.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext;
    operation.managedObjectCache = self.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
    operation.fetchRequestBlocks = self.fetchRequestBlocks;

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSManagedObject class]] && [[object objectID] isTemporaryID]) {
        RKLogInfo(@"Asked to perform object request with NSManagedObject with temporary object ID: Obtaining permanent ID before proceeding.");
        __block BOOL _blockSuccess;
        __block NSError *_blockError;

        [[object managedObjectContext] performBlockAndWait:^{
            _blockSuccess = [[object managedObjectContext] obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:@[object] error:&_blockError];
        }];
        if (! _blockSuccess) RKLogWarning(@"Failed to obtain permanent ID for object %@: %@", object, _blockError);
    }
    operation.targetObject = object;

    return operation;
}
```